# Why exactly is the condition $H_i \cap (H_1 \ldots H_{i-1} H_{i+1} \ldots H_n) = \{1\}$ not equivalent to $H_1 \cap H_2 \ldots \cap H_n = \{1\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The [internal n-fold direct product theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/250945/568976) says:

> A group $G$ is a $n$-fold product if and only if it has $n$ normal
>   subgroups $H_1,\ldots,H_n$ such that $G = H_1 \ldots H_n$ and $H_i
>  \cap (H_1 \ldots H_{i-1} H_{i+1} \ldots H_n) = \{1\}$.

Why is the independency condition for the subgroups written as $H_i \cap (H_1 \ldots H_{i-1} H_{i+1} \ldots H_n) = \{1\}$ rather than $H_1 \cap H_2 \ldots \cap H_n = \{1\}$? Is the latter condition stronger than the former? How? Could someone give me some examples? It's not really clear to me.

Comment: Actually, the former is stronger than the latter; added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the conditions are not the same, consider the Klein $4$-group $G=C_2\times C_2$, and take
$$\begin{align*}
H_1 &= \{(1,1), (x,1)\}\\
H_2 &= \{(1,1), (1,x)\}\\
H_3 &= \{(1,1), (x,x)\}
\end{align*}$$
where $x$ is the generator of the cyclic group of order $2$.

Note that $H_iH_j=G$ whenever $i\neq j$, so you never have $H_k\cap (H_iH_j)=\{(1,1)\}$ if $i\neq j$. However, $H_1\cap H_2\cap H_3 = \{(1,1)\}$.

Note that here the latter condition holds but the former does not, the latter cannot be stronger than the former.

To see that in fact the latter is **weaker** than the former, let us verify that the former condition implies the latter. That is: if $H_i\cap(H_1\cdots H_{i-1}H_{i+1}H_n = \{1\}$, then $H_1\cap H_2\cap\cdots \cap H_n=\{1\}$. This follows because each $H_j$ with $j\neq i$ is contained in the product $H_1\cdots H_{i-1}H_{i+1}\cdots H_n$ (by taking the identity in each of the other factors). So $$H_1\cap\cdots\cap H_n\subseteq H_1\cap H_2\subseteq H_1\cap(H_2\cdots H_n)=\{1\}.$$
Thus the former condition implies the latter, and so the former is stronger than the latter.

Comment: Interesting! By any chance, do these two conditions coincide when $H_1, \ldots, H_n$ are all normal subgroups? (Can you show it?)

Comment: Please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616955/how-does-the-independence-of-subgroups-condition-change-under-normality-of-subgr

Comment: @S.D. Do you not realize that in the example I gave you they are all normal subgroups?