# If every Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$ is normal for every prime $p$, then $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I want to prove  the following proposition.

> If every Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$ is normal for every prime $p$, then $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow groups.

**IDEA.**

I have the idea to use the following theorem.

**THEOREM**

If every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup, then $G$ is isomorphic to the product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: One part of Sylow's theorem is that $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on its Sylow $p$-subgroups. This is very useful.

Comment: Hey, this question has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250941/g-is-the-product-of-its-sylow-subgroups

Answer (score 0):

Let $L,M$ two different sylow groups. $x\in L, y\in M$, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in L\cap N$ implies that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$ since the order of $L$ and $M$ are relatively prime.
This implies that he subgroup  generated by the Sylow subgroups is isomorphic to the product of the Sylow subgroups  and its cardinal is the cardinal of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Try proving that any group has only one Sylow - $p$ - subgroup $H$ if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$.